# Extra textbox before input component

Tags: lightning-web-components, inputfield, lightninginput, text

It seems that there's an extra textbox that I can type into, but I'm not sure what's causing it in the code.

I only get to this extra textbox when tabbing through elements on the page.

I have added pictures of the UI and code snippets for the LWC where this is located.

```
                <div contenteditable="true" class={comboboxContainerClass}>
                    <div class={txtclassname} data-id="resultBox" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox">
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left-right">
                            <input
                                id="lookup-input"
                                placeholder={placeholder}
                                type="text"
                                required={required}
                                disabled={disabled}
                                data-id="userinput"
                                name="searchText"
                                onclick={resetAndSearch}
                                onfocusout={onblurInput}
                                onfocus={onFocus}
                                oninput={searchField}
                                value={selectRecordName}
                                class={comboboxInputClass}
                                autocomplete="off"
                            />
                            <div>
                                <lightning-icon if:true={hasIcon} class="slds-combobox__input-entity-icon" icon-name={iconName} size="x-small"  alternative-text="icon" ></lightning-icon>
                                <lightning-button-icon if:true={iconFlag} class="slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right pointable-icon" variant="bare" icon-name="utility:search" size="small" alternative-text="icon" onmousedown={onIconSearchClick} ></lightning-button-icon>
                                <lightning-button-icon if:true={clearIconFlag} class="slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right pointable-icon" variant="bare" icon-name="utility:close" size="small" alternative-text="icon" onmousedown={resetAndSearch} data-action="clear" ></lightning-button-icon>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to use the same code as there are some icons which I couldn't find, but I used this code:

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">Input Label</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left">
            <div class="slds-icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_left slds-icon-text-default" aria-hidden="true">
                <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:connected_apps" alternative-text="Connected" size="xx-small" title="small size">
                </lightning-icon>
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="text-input-id-1" placeholder="Placeholder text…" class="slds-input" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

So the logic is the input should come after the icon and place the icon inside div, so that the icon div takes its place and input tag comes right to the icon and when you navigate via tab it will directly take you to input field.

In your case move you icon div before input, and place these classes to move it to left. After that define your input tag.